# Angular ng-options "None" not working as expected when filtering results with an ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have reduced my app to the case below. I have two implementations of a select box, one with hard coded options and one using ng-options.

If you select a topic, and then go back to select "None", you'll observe the second example does not work the same way as the first example. I can't seem to configure ng-options correctly to get the behavior in the first example. The desired behavior is to show all items in the `friends` and `friends2` lists when no topic is selected.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

  $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', phone:'555-1276', topic: 'Baseball History', tags: ['Television, Sports']},
    {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY', topic: 'Presidential History', tags: ['Sports, America']},
    {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', topic: 'TV History', tags: ['History']},
    {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', topic: 'Texas Trivia', tags: ['Television, Sports, America, Politics']},
    {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', topic: '', tags: ['Sports']},
    {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'},
    {name:'Cliff', phone:'555-4444', topic: 'Baseball History', tags: ['Television']},
    {name:'Brad', phone:'800-HEYYOOO', topic: 'Presidential History', tags: ['Politics, America']},
    {name:'Susanne', phone:'555-5557', topic: 'TV History', tags: ['History']},
    {name:'Michelle', phone:'555-7777', topic: 'Texas Trivia', tags: ['Television, Sports, America']},
    {name:'Julie', phone:'555-1111', topic: '', tags: ['Sports']},
    {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-2222'}
   ]; 

  $scope.friends2 = [
    {name:'John', phone:'555-1276', topic: 'Baseball History', tags: ['Television, Sports']},
    {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY', topic: 'Presidential History', tags: ['Sports, America']},
    {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', topic: 'TV History', tags: ['History']},
    {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', topic: 'Texas Trivia', tags: ['Television, Sports, America, Politics']},
    {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', topic: '', tags: ['Sports']},
    {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'},
    {name:'Cliff', phone:'555-4444', topic: 'Baseball History', tags: ['Television']},
    {name:'Brad', phone:'800-HEYYOOO', topic: 'Presidential History', tags: ['Politics, America']},
    {name:'Susanne', phone:'555-5557', topic: 'TV History', tags: ['History']},
    {name:'Michelle', phone:'555-7777', topic: 'Texas Trivia', tags: ['Television, Sports, America']},
    {name:'Julie', phone:'555-1111', topic: '', tags: ['Sports']},
    {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-2222'}
   ]; 

  $scope.options = [
    {title: "Baseball History"},
    {title: "Presidential History"},
    {title: "TV History"},
    {title: "Texas Trivia"}
   ]
});
</script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <hr>
    Working select boxes, "None" works as expected.
    <hr>
    <br>by Topic
    <select ng-model="search.topic">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="Baseball History">Baseball History</option>
      <option value="Presidential History">Presidential History</option>
      <option value="TV History">TV History</option>
      <option value="Texas Trivia">Texas Trivia</option>
    </select>
    Selected: {{search.topic}}
    <br>
    <table id="searchObjResults">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search">
            <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
            <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    Working select boxes, "None" does not work as expected. All items are cleared.
    <hr>
    <br>by Topic
    <select ng-model="search2.topic" ng-options="option.title as option.title for option in options">
      <option value="">None</option>
    </select>
    Selected: {{search2.topic}}
    <br>
    <table id="searchObjResults">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friendObj2 in friends2 | filter:search2">
            <td>{{friendObj2.name}}</td>
            <td>{{friendObj2.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BCQrDYJoag7Fh0hPtwmk

In both examples, the value of the first option element is an empty string, however they behave differently. It has not been easy searching for another example of this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
As you have not included "None" in the options list,

1) You can either declare "None" in options list
2) you can use ng-repeat for the options. Please see below :

 <select ng-model="search2.topic">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option ng-repeat="option in options">{{option.title}}</option>
    </select>

Here is the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/KgTLxjqT8fH9UAco1D4w?p=preview
```

Comment: I prefer this solution the most. I don't want to "shim" my data arrays with the `{title: "None", value: ""}` technique. Thus, the result is less JS overhead and keeps my data model clean at the service level.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the 'none' entry in options array on line 41 and give each option a value:

```
$scope.options = [
      {title: "None",value: ""},
      {title: "Baseball History", value: "Baseball History"},
      {title: "Presidential History",value: "Presidential History"},
      {title: "TV History",value: "TV History"},
      {title: "Texas Trivia",value: "Texas Trivia"}
     ]
```

Then change the  on line 112 to:

```
<select ng-model="search2.topic" ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in options">

    </select>
```

Note how I've dropped the inline 'none' option markup and added it to the array above with appropriate value of "" to make the filter work.
Also note the use of option.value in the ng-options attribute.

Comment: Good answer. I've gone with the `ng-repeat` solution so as to not shim my actually data service with the extra object.

Answer (score 1):

The second example uses `ngOptions`. [From the docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

> Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This element will then represent the **null** or "not selected" option.

So it doesn't have an empty string as value, but `null`. Therefore it doesn't match with any friends having no topic, because "no topic" is represented as empty string, not `null`.

You can either add the "none" option to your `options` or represent "no topic" as `null`.

Comment: The none option is hard-coded in my ng-options example. Setting it to an empty string achieved the issue I posted here. Setting it to "null" has some weird behavior where the option disappears once you select an option with a real value. - http://plnkr.co/edit/waLTyx2vLQp9Fh8BjVes.

Comment: @BradGreens What I meant was setting the `topic` property of the friends without a topic to `null`. Your hard-coded option **already has** the value `null`, because the empty string there is treated as `null`. That's the what it's all about.

Comment: Gotcha. I got confused without an example. This seems to parallel the above answers, which show a couple ways of resolving why my hard-coded element was clearing the list due to matching against `null` instead of an empty string. Thanks for the tips.